# prevent windows program from screen capture

Tags: python, c#, windows, screenshot, screen-capture

How to create a program that cannot be screen captured?
I want my program to become **blacked** or **closed**, as soon as it detects that someone(another process) is capturing the screen.
OS: windows 8 or 10
screenshots are ok.(they are harmless)
programming languages: python or c#

p.s1 : I know there wouldn't be a perfect solution. I just want to find the best practical one.
p.s2 : I know someone could film with a camera. and that's just fine. I don't want to fight that.
p.s3 : The intention is a program for teaching, without someone copy it and distribute it all over the internet.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i prevent screen recording using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351709/how-can-i-prevent-screen-recording-using-c-sharp)

Comment: I'll give it a try. thanks.