# How does Disney+ prevent screen recordings of their content?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, screenshot

I tried to take a screenshot of a movie on the Disney+ web app when I realised that the video turns black as soon as I try to take a new screenshot with Snipping Tool. When I tried to do the same thing with OBS and Discord streams, I saw the same effect.

Interestingly, this only works for Chrome on my machine (I also tried Firefox and Edge and they just let me record my screen).

When I saw this, I became really curious on how they achieved this.
Does anyone have any idea how I can recreate this for my own web projects?

Comment: They use Widevine: https://ottverse.com/widevine-drm-how-does-it-work/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I became really curious on how they achieved this.

- [They use Widevine](https://www.reddit.com/r/PlayOn/comments/dln6ci/disney_will_require_widevine_l3_drm_so/).

  - [Widevine homepage](https://www.widevine.com/).
  - https://ottverse.com/widevine-drm-how-does-it-work/
  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widevine
  - News reports:

    - https://www.cordcuttersnews.com/sadly-disney-wont-work-on-chromebooks-linux-some-android-devices-because-of-drm/
    - https://www.tomsguide.com/news/disney-plus-will-work-on-chromebooks
    - https://www.androidpolice.com/2019/10/22/disney-will-only-work-on-devices-that-support-the-strictest-widevine-l3-drm/
- It's also used by Netflix, Hulu and others.
- Widevine is Google's DRM system that's baked-in to Chrome.

  - All other major browsers have adopted it as well, because no-one will use a browser that can't access Netflix.
  - Mozilla's and Microsoft's support is less *user-hostile* and as you noticed.
- It's just a standard HTML5 `<video>` element - when the browser downloads the video stream it will see that it's encrypted with Widevine and that engages the Widevine client-side code which does all the DRM biz.

  - Though [there are HTML and DOM features that facilitate DRM](https://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/), I'm unsure of [the extent that any JavaScript is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983555/is-there-a-way-to-use-drm-on-html5-video) to use it - as theoretically everything the browser needs to know to load the DRM system should be embedded in the raw media stream.
- On Windows, I understand (though unconfirmed) that Widevine makes use of [`SetWindowDisplayAffinity` to block screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268004/how-does-office-2013-implement-black-windows-for-irm).

  - Nothing stops you from doing this in your own native code (e.g. if you had an Electron fork), but *please don't* because it's a real dick-move to your users, in addition to not working at all if the user has the DWM disabled (e.g. they're running Windows 7 with Aero disabled).

> Has anyone any idea how I can recreate this for my own web projects?

You'll need to license Widevine yourself. [This is a complicated process intended only for large media production companies and content rightsholders](https://www.widevine.com/training), not individuals or small businesses.

Anyway, even if you could, *please don't*. Why would you want to make to harder for users to share and appreciate your media? Just stick it up on YouTube instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My initial thought was to use the feature as an additional security measure for critical data such as passwords. Not for DRM :D

Comment: @Manox That's a good point - I am surprised that Windows desktop password managers don't block screenshots (not taken by users, but by spyware) - though given that passwords are hardly ever displayed on-screen (instead we get dots/asterisks) I think the risk is overstated.